# How to properly load config table data into Admin Panel?

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml, table

I'm trying to create a config table using `ArraySerialized` and I'm able to save it to database and retrieve it via code, the problem is everytime I load my backend panel, my custom select field from config table are always loading the first value.

I tried to follow some examples I saw online, but none seemed to work for me.

This is my code so far:

In system.xml

```
<field id="commands_list" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="16" translate="label comment tooltip" type="text">
    <label>Commands List</label>
    <backend_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Serialized\ArraySerialized</backend_model>
    <frontend_model>Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Commands</frontend_model>
</field>
```

app\code\Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CommandsSelect.php

```
<?php

namespace Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class CommandsSelect extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select
{
    /**
     * @var \Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CommandsList
     */
    protected $_commandsList;

    public function __construct(
        \Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CommandsList $commandsList,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context, array $data = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_commandsList = $commandsList;
    }

    public function _toHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getOptions()) {
            foreach ($this->_commandsList->toOptionArray() as $option) {
                $this->addOption($option['value'], $option['label']);
            }
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getInputName();
    }
}
```

app\code\Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CommandsList.php

```
<?php

namespace Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class CommandsList implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * Provide available options as a value/label array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 1, 'label' => __("List Categories")),
            array('value' => 2, 'label' => __("Search For Product"))
        );
    }
}
```

app\code\Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Commands.php

```
<?php

namespace Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class Commands extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory
     */
    protected $_elementFactory;
    protected $_itemRendererCommands;
    protected $_itemRendererYesNo;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory,
        array $data = array()
    )
    {
        $this->_elementFactory  = $elementFactory;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->addColumn('command_id', array(
            'label' => __("Command"),
            'renderer' => $this->_getRendererCommands()
        ));
        $this->addColumn('enable_command', array(
            'label' => __("Enable Command"),
            'renderer' => $this->_getRendererYesNo()
        ));

        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __("Add");
        parent::_construct();
    }

    protected function _getRendererYesNo()
    {
        if (!$this->_itemRendererYesNo)
        {
            $this->_itemRendererYesNo = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Options\YesNo',
                '',
                array('data' => array('is_render_to_js_template' => true))
//                array('is_render_to_js_template' => true)
            ); // ->setExtraParams('style="width: 100%;"');
        }
        return $this->_itemRendererYesNo;
    }

    protected function _getRendererCommands()
    {
        if (!$this->_itemRendererCommands)
        {
            $this->_itemRendererCommands = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Werules\Chatbot\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\CommandsSelect',
                '',
                array('data' => array('is_render_to_js_template' => true))
//                array('is_render_to_js_template' => true)
            ); // ->setExtraParams('style="width: 100%;"');
        }
        return $this->_itemRendererCommands;
    }

    protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $optionExtraAttr = array();
        $optionExtraAttr['option_' . $this->_getRendererCommands()->calcOptionHash($row->getData('command_id'))] = 'selected="selected"';
        $row->setData(
            'option_extra_attrs', $optionExtraAttr
        );
        $optionExtraAttr = array();
        $optionExtraAttr['option_' . $this->_getRendererYesNo()->calcOptionHash($row->getData('enable_command'))] = 'selected="selected"';
        $row->setData(
            'option_extra_attrs', $optionExtraAttr
        );
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh boy... that was silly. I was rewriting the variable `$optionExtraAttr` assigning a new array to it with `$optionExtraAttr = array();`.

Well, fixed, not a Magento error at least.